# How to Handle Elastic Search rage query that has a negative value such as a longitude point

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I have a index with values of customers I need to be able to filter the records between ranges for longitude values on a map. The filter for latitude works.
I was wondering if it wasn't filtering longitude because of negative values.

After some research I found out that I could try using an escape key because '-' could be interpreted wrong.  Neither with or without the escape characters worked.

- note - there are records between that range because when I grab the whole index I can see the records with longitude values between the range.

I have no clue what else I can try. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Example :

[image]

Comment: Can you share your mapping ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure the data-type of your `longitude` field, as [geo-point data type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-point.html) doesn't support the range queries, and if you use the normal integer than it works, as shown below.

**Index sample documents with default integer mapping**

```
put my-idx-number-range/_doc/4
{
  "longitutde" : -10
}
put my-idx-number-range/_doc/4
{
  "longitutde" : 20
}
put my-idx-number-range/_doc/4
{
  "longitutde" : 10
}
put my-idx-number-range/_doc/4
{
  "longitutde" : 50
}
```

**Search query with ranges**

```
POST my-idx-number-range/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "longitutde": {
              "gte": -73,
              "lte": 20
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**And search result**

```
 "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "my-idx-number-range",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 0.0,
        "_source" : {
          "longitutde" : -20
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "my-idx-number-range",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 0.0,
        "_source" : {
          "longitutde" : 20
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "my-idx-number-range",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "3",
        "_score" : 0.0,
        "_source" : {
          "longitutde" : 10
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Thank you so much !!! ,  I recently was handed off this project from another team. I didn't realize the index they created was using text field lol.  So ill be recreating a text index and assign the appropriate types.